# Java HttpUrlConnection international characters in url redirect

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have a problem with obtaining content of some websites. When I try navigating to url that redirects to another url, which contains international characters, java usually gets error 404. When I follow this url in browser, I get valid data.

For example I want to navigate to hXXp://shar.es/cISmv (can't post more than 2 valid links)

Browser redirects me correctly to hXXp://www.dandy-magazine.com/la-griffe-de-la-tour-d%E2%80%99argent . From wget I can see that initially site returns redirect 301 with existing "Location: http://www.dandy-magazine.com/la-griffe-de-la-tour-d%E2%80%99argent"

In java (whith redirects turned off) it returns redirect 301 with "`Location: http://www.dandy-magazine.com/la-griffe-de-la-tour-dâargent`". With url encoding ot looks like this: "`http://www.dandy-magazine.com/la-griffe-de-la-tour-d%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%99argent`". As you can see, it's totally different site.

Sample code (basically version 1 and version 2 does the same thing):

```
// version 1 - let java handle redirects
URL url = new URL("http://shar.es/cISmv");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
con.getResponseCode();
return con.getURL(); // returned url is not what it should be

// version 2 - I want to handle redirects
URL url = new URL("http://shar.es/cISmv");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
con.getResponseCode();
String loc = con.getHeaderField("Location");
// here is the problem, loc is not initialized with a correct url
// returned String corresponds to url returned in version 1
```

Thx for help

Comment: be careful to use the correct charset encoding. the first link you posted is probably encoded in iso 8859-1 while the second one is encoded in unicode.

Comment: hi, thx for comment. I slightly clarified the question. Basically my problem is that I get different redirection result when I want to access the same site from java and from web browser. I suspected that the problem might be in character encodings, but how do I know what encoding is used? And how do I set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Java is not handling the Location header when it's value is UTF-8 encoded.

The URL is supposed to look like .../la-griffe-de-la-tour-d'argent.  Note that in the previous sentence I am using the ASCII single-quote character.  However instead of using the single quote character the web site chose to use the unicode character

```
00002019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
Glyph: ’
UTF-8: E2 80 99
```

A wireshark trace reveals that the returned Location header has this character UTF-8 encoded.

```
00e0  65 70 2d 61 6c 69 76 65  0d 0a 4c 6f 63 61 74 69   ep-alive ..Locati
00f0  6f 6e 3a 20 68 74 74 70  3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 64   on: http ://www.d
0100  61 6e 64 79 2d 6d 61 67  61 7a 69 6e 65 2e 63 6f   andy-mag azine.co
0110  6d 2f 6c 61 2d 67 72 69  66 66 65 2d 64 65 2d 6c   m/la-gri ffe-de-l
0120  61 2d 74 6f 75 72 2d 64  e2 80 99 61 72 67 65 6e   a-tour-d ...argen
0130  74 0d 0a 0d 0a 30 0d 0a  0d 0a                     t....0.. ..
```

I don't know if this is legal HTTP.  There are definitely a lot of questions about this on the web.  Regardless of whether it is legal or not, the HttpURLConnection class does not handle it well.  The call to

```
String loc = con.getHeaderField("Location");
```

should have returned the string `http://www.dandy-magazine.com/la-griffe-de-la-tour-d’argent` where there was a single character (2019) between `d` and `argent`.  Instead it return an invalid string by doing a dumb conversion of each of those 3 UTF-8 bytes into characters (E2 80 99).  At this point the "loc" string is useless.  It's not a valid unicode string.

Here is a workaround that might help:

```
  String loc = con.getHeaderField("Location");
  byte [] locbytes = new byte[loc.length()];
  for (int index = 0; index < locbytes.length; index++)
  {
     locbytes[index] = (byte) loc.charAt(index);
  }

  // use this loc instead
  String loc2 = new String(locbytes, "UTF-8");
```

Convert the bogus string (where each char has the value of the byte that was sent by the web server) back into a byte array.  Then convert the byte array back to a string using the proper character set.  Now open a new connection using loc2 as your URL.

There is probably a better way to do this but I have not examined the source implementation to figure out of there is a way to tell the HttpURLConnection class to treat header values as UTF-8 encoded.